# text hangs outside the DIV

Tags: html, css, division

The text hangs outside of the DIV container. Perhaps I have the wrong elements in my CSS. On my actual website it hangs below but when I check snippet here it doesn't hang. Here is the code.

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urfTe.jpg)

```css
.bodybox {
    height:65px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#000000; 
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0 #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0 #000000;
    border: solid 2px #ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: -350px;
    top: 27px;
    font-family: 'Jura', serif;
    font-size: 45px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodybox">
    Print
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of what's happening on your website?

Comment: yes, just added it, thanks

Comment: Try removing the `top` attribute

Comment: can you link to your site? without seeing the code that replicates the problem, we're just taking shots in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bodybox {
    height:65px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#000000; 
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0 #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0 #000000;
    border: solid 2px #ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
   //left: -350px;
    
    font-family: 'Jura', serif;
    font-size: 45px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:flex;
}

.bodybox span{
  margin : auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodybox">
    <span>Print</span>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svkq2nr2/1/)

Hope this helps.